# Interior-point linear programing solver in MATLAB, with target barrier parameter option

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, ipopt

Is there any linear programing solver, written for MATLAB, that (a) solves with the primal-dual interior point method, (b) the user has the options to set the target barrier parameter (he lowest value of barrier parameter for which the KKT system is solved)?

I currently use IPOPT, which has the target barrier parameter options.
However, at convergence, the product of dual*slack seems to only be approximately satisfied (with an error of say (+-)1e-7 for a target parameter of 1e-5).
I have tried to play around with the tolerances, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

For MATLAB use, I recommend using [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/solver.html), which includes Gurobi, MOSEK, GLPK, and SDPT3. All of those can solve the linear program very efficiently.

CVX is very easy to use in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Indeed I can use CVX for MATLAB for ease.
However, I was more interested in an interior point LP solver with target barrier parameter option, since I need to partially solve LPs in my work.